# Easier proof of : Show that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = a^2 + b^2 - c^3.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that the statement above is true according to the following identities :

for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$,
$$2x + 1 = (x^3 - 3x^2 + x)^2 + (x^2 - x - 1)^2 - (x^2 - 2x)^3$$
$$2(2x + 1) = (2x^3 - 2x^2 - x)^2 + (2x^3 - 4x^2 - x + 1)^2 - (2x^2 - 2x - 1)^3$$
$$4(2x + 1) = (x^3 + x + 2)^2 + (x^2 - 2x - 1)^2 - (x^2 + 1)^3$$

and for all $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$,
$$8(x^2 + y^2 - z^3) = (2x + 2y)^2 + (2x - 2y)^2 - (2z)^3.$$

(You can go check it by using Wolfram Alpha.)
Since there exists $k, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = 2^k \cdot m$ and $2 \not|\:\:m$, let $x = \frac{b-1}{2}$ then we can express $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = a^2 + b^2 - c^3$ using the identities above.

It is an intuitive proof, but it is quite difficult to find the right polynomials and most of all : it is not beautiful. I think it can be approached with number theories though. I wonder if there are other proofs possible.

Comment: "but it is quite difficult to find the right polynomials" - As explained in the other answer, it is not so difficult.  I think the proof is nice and elementary. No need for advanced number theory methods here. I don't believe that there is an easier proof than the one given everywhere (art of problem solving etc.).

Comment: As Will Jagy commented, this was also a posted at MAA monthly [here](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Elkies_Kap.pdf), with solution. It seems that there were several solutions send in, but all very similar to the one we know. This problem with two squares and a cube was proposed by Elkies and Kaplansky!